# How can I replace 'æ' 'ø' and 'å' in a text without error: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, non-ascii-characters

I am making a program which is supposed to open a textfile, then replace letters 'æ, ø, and å' (Danish text) with 'ae, oe, aa'.
I need to open the program and run it through the mac terminal.
I tried using the replace() function, and tried writing:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

in the beginning of the file.

But I keep getting error: 
     File "replace.py", line 20, in replace_nonascii
     word = word.replace('å', 'aa')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

any suggestions? have tried googling this for days, I have no clue how to fix it.

Here is my program:

```
filepath = input('insert path for text')

with codecs.open(filepath, 'r', encoding = 'utf8') as file_object:
    filename_cont['text1'] = file_object.read()


def replace_nonascii(word):
    word = word.lower()
    word = word.replace('å', 'aa')
    word = word.replace('æ', 'ae')
    word = word.strip('/-.,?!')
    print(word)

for text in filename_cont:
    newtext = filename_cont[text]
    for word in newtext.split():
        replace_nonascii(word)
```

Comment: This is tagged [unicode], so I'm obliged to point out that the idea to replace characters in an attempt to achieve something useful (which is not mentioned here) is an instance of the [XY problem](http://enwp.org/XY_problem). I'm *guessing* you want to compare or sort on text – Unicode collation is powerful enough without needing to get rid of non-ASCII.

Comment: Every text file has a character encoding. You have to know it before starting. It's even more important than the file name.

Comment: Python 2 and 3 differ in their handling of Unicode.  Which are you using?

Comment: Try creating a [mcve].  The code should be complete and run without changes to produce the error.  The code above won't run (no input file, and `filename_cont` doesn't exist).